# Site passed Mobile Friendly test, label does not appear

Tags: search, mobile

My site passed Google's mobile friendly test a few weeks ago. The "Mobile-friendly" label does not appear in the mobile search results though. How long will this take?

Thanks!

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how dynamic your content is determines how often your site is crawled/indexed. I would do a fetch and render, then wait a few weeks or so.